# How to dynamically register commands and schedulers in laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am working on a composer package which is used by multiple laravel 5 application so I have a service provider in there which hooks the goodies into laravel 5 application when installed in one.

I know I can register service providers for dependent packages like so:

```
$this->app->register(\Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider::class);
$this->app->register(\EvanDarwin\JSend\Laravel\ServiceProvider::class);
$this->app->register(\Prettus\Repository\Providers\RepositoryServiceProvider::class);
```

I know I can also load aliases like so:

```
$loader = \Illuminate\Foundation\AliasLoader::getInstance();
$loader->alias('Excel', 'Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel');
$loader->alias('Firewall', 'PragmaRX\Firewall\Vendor\Laravel\Facade');
```

But what about registering commands and schedule calls? Are there methods to do that too? If yes, how do I do it?

I am newbie trying to learn good OOP practices and I get stuck in such things. So more importantly, where do I go looking for such stuff? Is there documentation for this too? Because I couldn't find this stuff in the Package Development section at laravel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Service Provider has a `commands()` method that will register a command with artisan. You can use it like so:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->singleton('command.goodies.yourcommand', function ($app) {
        return $app['Your\Namespace\Commands\YourCommand'];
    });
    $this->commands('command.goodies.yourcommand');
}
```

As far as setting a scheduled task, I don't believe that can (or should) be done from your package. Registering the command gives the user the tool to use. However, scheduling the task is trying to use the tool for them. That should be left up to the user to do.

Your best bet is to be very clear in your documentation on how to schedule the task and what your recommendations may be. The "how-to" should also include entering the cron job, as this may be the user's first time setting up a scheduled task.

Comment: Yeah I `dd(get_class_methods($this));` in the service provider and figured the commands method out myself. And yes it makes sense that the scheduling must not be done automatically. Thank you anyway. :)

Comment: I'll award you the bounty when Stack lets me.

Comment: @Rohan I appreciate it. I'm glad you were able to figure this out yourself, as well. In addition to your way of finding the function, you can also dig into the source code. It may take a little bit to figure out how everything is put together, but you really do learn a lot. And, of course, there's the [api docs](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/).

Comment: This is very easy, thanks a lot! Still wonder why it's not in the doc.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically register command not built in the framework. But you can create it manually.

Edit.

`app/Console/Kernel.php`

Add a new method

```
public function addCommand($command)
{
    $this->commands[] = $command;
}
```

Then, in a controller or in a service provider add a new command.

```
  $console = app()->make(\Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class);

  $console->addCommand(YourCommand::class);
```

As for a second question, dynamically schedule, I don't think it's possible in an easy way

Comment: But this doesn't really help me. Every time the package that I am creating will be installed, it will have to be done manually. There is no other reason I want to do it dynamically but to make it easier for the consumer of the package.